# How do I permanently make an element visible in css3?

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a text-based game that a user will only read at the beginning.

and then my button which is called "begin" shows up at the end but the problem is that it **fades away and the user will not be able to see it anymore because its hidden**

I tried using the animation titled *fadeIn* to make it visible.

```css
#message_.active h1.five{
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0;
    animation: fadeIn 10s linear;
    animation-delay: 53s;
    font-family: 'Edu SA Beginner', cursive;
    top: 50px;
    left: 160px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
 0%,100% { opacity: 1 }
}
```

```html
<div id="message_" class="active">
  <h1 class="five">text</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: `animation-delay: 53s;` ? 53 seems like a typo

Comment: `0%,100% { opacity: 1 }`
 doesn't make any sense. did you mean `0%{opacity: 0; } 100% { opacity: 1 }` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[with a little effort you could have found this on your own...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode)

```css
animation-fill-mode : forwards;
```

```css
#message_.active h1.five{
  position            : relative;
  opacity             : 0;
  animation           : fadeIn 10s linear;
  animation-fill-mode : forwards;
  animation-delay     : 2s; /* why waiting 53s for a test code to start ? */
  font-family         : 'Edu SA Beginner', cursive;
  top                 : 50px;
  left                : 160px;
  cursor              : pointer;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0%   { opacity: 0 }
  100% { opacity: 1 }
  }
```

```html
<div id="message_" class="active">
  <h1 class="five">text</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, it worked. Thank you so much ^^ @Mister Jojo                                                        I have many texts before this so it had to wait haha